# Why do we need web.config in ASP .NET 5 wwwroot?

Tags: web-config, asp.net-core

In ASP .NET 5, [Configuration](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingconfig.html) is changing drastically. We no longer have a `web.config` file. Instead, we can use JSON and other options, depending on how we set things up in our `Startup` class. Unlike `web.config`, such configuration typically doesn't go in `wwwroot`, and there is no danger that clients can gain access to it.

And yet, in the ASP .NET 5 project templates there's a `web.config` file in `wwwroot` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It seems to me that this could be something that the hosting server is looking for at runtime, independently of the application configuration.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is needed, and how it works?

Comment: Is this still needed?

Comment: Yes, you still need web.config if you are hosting ASP .NET Core in IIS, though the actual content of the config file may have changed.

Comment: I have the web.config file not in the wwwroot/ folder. I just wondered if I needed both the normal web.config which has the AspNetCore IIS module AND the one shown above which is in the wwwroot.

Comment: I think you just need the one with the AspNetCore IIS module. In retrospect, I can't remember how having web.config in wwwroot was a good idea back then.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Web.config is strictly for IIS Configuration. It is not needed unless hosting in IIS. It is not used when you run the app from the command line.

In the past Web.config was used for both IIS configuration and application configuration and settings. But in asp.net 5 it is not used by the application at all, it is only used for IIS configuration.

This decoupling of the application from IIS is part of what makes cross platform possible.

Comment: note that as of ASP.NET Core RTM, the web.config file (which is still only for IIS) doesn't go in the wwwroot folder anymore but goes in the root of the application outside of wwwroot.