# HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModuleV2" in its module list even after installing bundles

Tags: angular, .net-core, hosting, web-hosting

I am getting this error

```
  HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
  Handler "aspNetCore" has a bad module "AspNetCoreModuleV2" in its module list
```

i published my project in the release mode, and using filezilla i published it to my godaddy hosting space. When i try to open the site using URL i am getting this following error.

Anything idea?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nithin Paul, did you try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54539874/3520507)?

Comment: DArkSideMoon, this bundle installation is to perform at my hosting machine  right? not in my local machine in which i am developing my applciation? I am using godaddy to host this app,

Comment: yes, you right. You should install bundle on your hosting machine

Comment: In go daddy how will i do it? using connecting using remote desktop? using ip? i tried it but was not able to connect it before?

Comment: What `OS` did you use for hosting in godaddy? Is it Windows server and IIS?

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: Another thing is we are using share hosting, Means we purchased our domain in gsuit and later we moved to godaddy, so under which space we need to install this bundles

Comment: It is interesting, because the solution of this problem it is install `hosting bundle` on the machine using ftp client such as [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php). But I found the same problem in [godaddy support](https://uk.godaddy.com/community/GoDaddy-Web-Hosting/HTTP-Error-500-21-Internal-Server-Error/td-p/157069) - they said _They don't support .net core 3_

Comment: Well, you can try to install `hosting bundle`. This is [guide](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_connect) how to connecto to the server. But I think you don't have right to install any additional software on theirs machines - that is way support said that - **They don't support .net core 3**

Comment: Correct version of hosting bundle you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#install-the-aspnet-core-modulehosting-bundle)

Comment: Ohh :/ that means i need to move to .net corelates then :( let me check your link to connect to remote desktop. and will try to install these bundles,

Comment: Yes, try it. Maybe it helps. Write here after you try.

Comment: Otherwise, there are a lot of others hosting servers for .net core.

Comment: Sure darksidemoon,  i will update, anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem :) 
I think we will continue discussion here and I will write answer on your question after our investigation about install hosting bundle. I think the best wasy to solve problem, change hosting provider.

Comment: Go daddy's shared hosting is supported till 2.0 now, and they want me to purchase VPS which is little expensive. So either i may need to consider another hosting provider or need to downgrade my app to 2.0

Comment: I will be preferred to change hosting, because we have net core 5.0 with a lot of new features, but they support only 2.0

Comment: Why did you migrate from google hosting? Is it expensive?

Answer (score 3):

After invetigation issue - I found [support answer](https://uk.godaddy.com/community/GoDaddy-Web-Hosting/HTTP-Error-500-21-Internal-Server-Error/td-p/157069) in godaddy site - **They don't support .net core 3**

The best way to solve this issue - **migrate to other hosting server**

There are severals hosting servers that support net core:

- [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/) - [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)
- [Google](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet) - [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-dotnet-applications)
- [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/developer/language/net/?whats-new-dotnet.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-dotnet.sort-order=desc) - [Example](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/)
- [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) - [Example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-core-application-with-mysql-server-using-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Also, my recommendation **do not deploy** .Net core application in windows server in IIS.
Deploy your application in Linux.
[image: Net Core with Linux]

Comment: Finally the site is up, had to down grade my .net target framework to 2.0. Had to do some coding changes in startup.cd file otherwise didnt create any major issues DarkSideMoon